# How to save the value of a cell of a DataGridView before edition for undo purpose?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, undo

I am adding an undo feature for a DataGridView using the Command Design Pattern.

To create the EditCommand, I have to know what was the previous value of the cell, so I can re-enter it in case the user hits undo.

I'm doing it using the CellBeginEdit and CellEndEdit events.

With the CellBeginEdit, I save the value of the cell in a private variable and at the CellEndEdit function, I use the saved value to create the EditCommand.

It's working fine, but I wonder if there is a more saner way to do it. Maybe a event that holds together the previous and the new cell value.

Bonus points if I could actually prevent the DataGridView from updating itself and let the EditCommand do it.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented Undo / Redo in a large WPF application, and was able to extract the Undo / Redo logic into a stand-alone library. This is available on CodePlex.

The library helps keep a stack of history that can be re-applied if the user elects to undo / redo. This could replace your private variables and also allow for multiple items in the undo history.

You can find documentation and downloads at http://muf.codeplex.com/

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but I would like to continue to use the Command design. Also, I already have a stack for undo/redo. The problem is which events to use.

Comment: Have you looked into the BindingGroup? This is what the DataGrid uses to manage and apply the values. If you want to manage things at a row level (rather than a cell level) or if you want to alter the behavior related to committing the bindings, then the BindingGroup might be a good bet.